# Firebase Functions running locally not authenticating with Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm able to successfully run this code when deployed to a Firebase project.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  admin.auth().createUser({ uid: req.body.id })
    .then(user => {
      return res.send(user);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return res.status(422).send({ error: err });
    });
});
```

This is the response from Firebase:

```
{
    "uid": "abcdefg1234",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "disabled": false,
    "metadata": {
        "lastSignInTime": null,
        "creationTime": "Sun, 20 May 2018 22:22:55 GMT"
    },
    "tokensValidAfterTime": "Sun, 20 May 2018 22:22:55 GMT",
    "providerData": []
}
```

However, when I run the functions *locally* with `firebase serve` and call the same function (with Postman), I run into a permission errors:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "auth/insufficient-permission",
        "message": "Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property has insufficient permission to access the requested resource. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for details on how to authenticate this SDK with appropriate permissions."
    }
}
```

Is the authentication setup for firebase-admin on a locally running Firebase Functions instance different than when running on the normal, production Firebase servers?

Specs:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

> If you want your functions tests to interact with Google APIs or other
>   Firebase APIs via the Firebase Admin SDK, you may need to set up admin
>   credentials
>
> Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database triggers already have sufficient
>   credentials, and do not require additional setup.
>
> All other APIs, including Firebase APIs such as Authentication and FCM
>   or Google APIs such as Cloud Translation or Cloud Speech, require the
>   setup steps described in this section. This applies whether you're
>   using the functions shell or firebase serve.

So it appears that the answer to the question is "yes", you may need a different auth process depending on which Firebase services you are accessing.